# PL/SQL stack trace maximum size (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to retrieve the pl/sql stack trace in Java when a call to a stored procedure fails.

I can access the stack trace but the size is limited somehow. How can I increase the maximum size of the stack trace? I have tried directly retrieve the stack trace using 'DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE()' but I face the same limitation.

Comment: can you please post the jdbc code to understand the problem better

Comment: I appreciate both the question and answer; however, I can't find any documentation stating the limit of characters for DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE. Could you include the actual limit you're facing in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to increase the trace depth. You have to implement your own way to track it deeper. Either add a integer v_step and keep incrementing it in different parts of your code.(Like bread crumbs) and return it to the caller. Or keep logging in a Log table or any `UTL_FILE` in your `PL/SQL`, based on a debug flag.

So you identify, till where you came. You can try the debugger option in any IDE like `SQL Developer` or `TOAD`, provided you are not behind a firewall. But you need to run a `PL/SQL` with same parameters you use in `JDBC`. I understand it is painful. Good Luck.!

**EDIT:** Surprisingly Oracle 12c comes with a brand new UTL_CALL_STACK() to give a detailed info.

http://technology.amis.nl/2013/06/26/oracle-database-12c-plsql-package-utl_call_stack-for-programmatically-inspecting-the-plsql-call-stack/